What is objid and group in Lustre file striping info?
I have created two files data.txt with stripe count as 2 and datathree.txt with stripe count as 3.
 The striping details are as follows.
[pravs@lustre-dev lustre-client]$ lfs getstripe normal_layout/
normal_layout/
stripe_count:  2 stripe_size:   1048576 pattern:       raid0 stripe_offset: -1

normal_layout//datathree.txt
lmm_stripe_count:  3
lmm_stripe_size:   1048576
lmm_pattern:       raid0
lmm_layout_gen:    0
lmm_stripe_offset: 3
        obdidx           objid           objid           group
             3               3            0x3      0x300000400
             0               5            0x5      0x280000400
             1               4            0x4      0x2c0000400

normal_layout//data.txt
lmm_stripe_count:  2
lmm_stripe_size:   1048576
lmm_pattern:       raid0
lmm_layout_gen:    0
lmm_stripe_offset: 0
        obdidx           objid           objid           group
             0               3            0x3      0x280000400
             1               3            0x3      0x2c0000400


So what is the objid and group mean here?
Need clarification on what objid and group mean here?
